# Devexpress GridControl VB NET

Tags: devexpress, gridcontrol, devexpress-gridcontrol

Hi i'm getting an error here . What can i do for?

```
TextBox1.Text = GDLoadCaixa.Item(0, GDLoadCaixa.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
```

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State

> Error BC30456 'Item' is not a member of 'GridControl'.

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State

> Error BC30456 'CurrentRow' is not a member of 'GridControl'.

Comment: yes I have a project with datagridview and i'll change to gridcondrol  ( devexpress )

Comment: I suggest using the DevExpress documentation to figure out the syntax for what you are trying to do.  The syntax of the 2 controls is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was

textbox1.text= gridView1.Columns.View .GetFocusedRowCellValue ("id")

Comment: It should be `textbox1.text = gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("id")`